# "Error 503. Service Unavailable" error on cPanel for a NodeJS Project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cpanel, http-status-code-503

So I'm new to NodeJS and cPanel. I've already successfully setup a static website and a redirect website with cPanel, but this is my first NodeJS project. My app seems to fail once I add things like express and mongo.

I've tested the "Setup NodeJS" app on cPanel with a simple, res.send() code and it seems to work. However, once my code gets complicated and uses other packages, it stops working. I'm assuming that it's an issue with the retrieval of the packages or versions. However, I've tried every version of Node on cPanel and it still doesn't work. I've also registered my app with the Application Manager.

**Note**: I'm using a shared hosting plan on Namecheap.

My app.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const connectDB = require('./server/config/db');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI
    })
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

connectDB();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('layout', './layouts/main');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', require('./server/routes/auth'))
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/index'));
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/dashboard'));


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('404 Page Not Found')
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

**UPDATE**:

I tried messing around with my env variables. I managed to make it work for a second, but it failed as soon as I logged in with google. I believe me callback url may be the issue. I've attached the image of my env variables below.

[env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPTLw.png)

Now, the website just doesn't seem to work at all. Even after I changed everything back to normal. I stopped getting a normal "503 error" and now I'm getting something that seems like a res.send() with a message saying "Internal Server Error".